# Streambuilder with WebSockets stream in TabBarView: Bad state: Stream has already been listened to

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket

I want to listen to a websocket stream inside a Widget which is displayed in a TabBarView:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/io.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/web_socket_channel.dart';

class RabitHouse extends StatefulWidget {
  final channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect('ws://echo.websocket.org');

  @override
  _RabitHouseState createState() => _RabitHouseState();
}

class _RabitHouseState extends State<RabitHouse> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(tabs: [
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.adb,
                ),
              ),
              Tab(
                  icon: Icon(
                Icons.android,
              )),
            ]),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(children: [
            Rabit(channel: widget.channel),
            Rabit(channel: widget.channel),
          ]),
        ));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.channel.sink.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class Rabit extends StatefulWidget {
  final WebSocketChannel channel;

  const Rabit({Key key, this.channel}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RabitState createState() => _RabitState();
}

class _RabitState extends State<Rabit> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: widget.channel.stream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) => Text('pew pew'),
    );
  }
}
```

However when I change the Tab I get an Exception:

> ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>   The following StateError was thrown building Rabit(state: _RabitState#cd14b):
>   Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Streams in Dart are single-listener by default, meaning if you try to listen to them more than once, they will throw an error. If you want to listen to a stream in multiple places, you need to convert it to a broadcast stream:

```dart
class _RabitHouseState extends State<RabitHouse> {
  Stream broadcastStream;

  @override
  void initState() {
    broadcastStream = widget.channel.stream.asBroadcastStream();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(tabs: [
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.adb,
                ),
              ),
              Tab(
                  icon: Icon(
                Icons.android,
              )),
            ]),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(children: [
            Rabit(stream: broadcastStream),
            Rabit(stream: broadcastStream),
          ]),
        ));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.channel.sink.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

```dart
class Rabit extends StatefulWidget {
  final Stream stream;

  const Rabit({Key key, this.stream}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RabitState createState() => _RabitState();
}

class _RabitState extends State<Rabit> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: widget.stream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) => Text('pew pew'),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Ty so far! I get "The method 'close' isn’t defined for the class 'Stream'". Any ideas?

Comment: @ynotu. My mistake, `Steam` doesn't have a `close` method. Just remove it.

Comment: so converting the stream to broadcastStream AND passing the stream instead of the channel to the Rabit Widget, did the trick! Ty for you help!

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to the same stream if you "subscribe" to it twice. Creating two WebSocket channels and then listening to both of them as `asBroadcastStream()`:

```
class RabitHouse extends StatefulWidget {
  final channel1 = IOWebSocketChannel.connect('ws://echo.websocket.org');
  final channel2 = IOWebSocketChannel.connect('ws://echo.websocket.org');

  @override
  _RabitHouseState createState() => _RabitHouseState();
}

class _RabitHouseState extends State<RabitHouse> {
  Stream stream1;
  Stream stream2;

  @override
  void initState() {
    stream1  = widget.channel1.stream.asBroadcastStream();
    stream2  = widget.channel2.stream.asBroadcastStream();

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(tabs: [
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.adb,
                ),
              ),
              Tab(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.android,
                  )
              ),
            ]),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(children: [
            Rabit(stream: stream1),
            Rabit(stream: stream2),
          ]),
        )
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.channel1.sink.close();
    widget.channel2.sink.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class Rabit extends StatefulWidget {
  final Stream stream;

  const Rabit({Key key, this.stream}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RabitState createState() => _RabitState();
}

class _RabitState extends State<Rabit> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: widget.stream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) => Text('pew pew'),
    );
  }
}
```

**If you want to learn more about streams, from [dart.dev](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams)**

> **There are two kinds of streams**
>
> **Single subscription streams** The most common kind of stream contains a
>   sequence of events that are parts of a larger whole. Events need to be
>   delivered in the correct order and without missing any of them. This
>   is the kind of stream you get when you read a file or receive a web
>   request.
>
> Such a stream can only be listened to once. Listening again later
>   could mean missing out on initial events, and then the rest of the
>   stream makes no sense. When you start listening, the data will be
>   fetched and provided in chunks.
>
> **Broadcast streams** The other kind of stream is intended for individual
>   messages that can be handled one at a time. This kind of stream can be
>   used for mouse events in a browser, for example.
>
> You can start listening to such a stream at any time, and you get the
>   events that are fired while you listen. More than one listener can
>   listen at the same time, and you can listen again later after
>   canceling a previous subscription.

Comment: Ty! If you convert it to a broadcast stream and pass the stream (instead of the channel, as I did) to the rabits, one WebSocketChannel is enough.